# Specific version of MongoDB on OpenShift: How?

Tags: mongodb, openshift

Currently OpenShift provides a cartridge for MongoDB 2.4. MongoDB 2.6 has been out for a while now and I need it for its fantastic text index and query support. I know it's possible to create and install custom cartridges, but the process looks surprisingly complex. Before I delve into that, I'm wondering if there are any other options -- or at least tools that might make less work of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's been a white since this thread started, but while facing the same problem last year, I've built this:

[Custom cartridge for OpenShift providing MongoDB > 3.x](https://github.com/icflorescu/openshift-cartridge-mongodb)

Make sure to have a look at the repo README to see if it fits your needs.

Comment: Very cool, I-C. I ended up leaving OpenShift and just set up on EC2 ultimately, but I'm sure this will be very useful to others as it was exactly what I hoped to find at the time I asked, so I'm marking this as the accepted answer. I'm surprised that even now OpenShift is still stuck on 2.4!

Answer (score 0):

Mongodb 2.6 is planned for OPenshift and you can help push it along by voting on the card here: https://trello.com/c/mQjfeMFC. As for options today, you could use a DBaaS and I think MongoHQ (now compose) has 2.6 available https://www.compose.io/.

If DBaaS isn't an option than you could take a crack at creating your own cartridge, which isn't really that difficult especially since you could copy alot of the stuff from https://github.com/openshift/origin-server/tree/master/cartridges/openshift-origin-cartridge-mongodb.

Comment: Thanks, the Trello link at least let me feel like I got to communicate with the Openshift folks in some sense (I'm a little perplexed by their decision to eliminate public forums and shunt all questions to SO). Compose.IO looks great, but $54 is a lot more than the $4 we anticipate spending per month with OpenShift (it's not for a huge db). I'll give the last suggestion a try. You don't happen to know roughly when 2.6 is likely to happen for OpenShift, do you? If it's in less than four months, I can stand to wait.

Comment: I feel like an idiot, but my main stumbling block so far is that while I've determined that I must add the actual MongoDB package dependencies in the spec file, I don't have the faintest clue how. The 4.2 dependencies are four packages (mongodb24-mongodb, mongodb24-libmongodb, etc) that don't seem to have 2.6 equivalents in RHEL. Mongo has its own repo with current versions, but I can't figure out how to indicate the repository, and anyway they don't even seem to correspond to the packages used for 2.4. I suspect I just don't have the RedHat wherewithal to even be approaching this. :/

Answer (score 0):

OpenShift offers MongoDB 2.4 but they are partnering with [MongoLab](https://mongolab.com/) who offer MongoDB 2.6 for productive operation and 3.0.4  for sandbox experimentation.

There is also a page to check which MongoDB versions are currently available at MongoLab:
http://docs.mongolab.com/ops/#available-versions

More useful information about the use of OpenShift with MongoLab:

- [How to use MongoDB on RedHat OpenShift with MongoLab](http://blog.mongolab.com/2013/04/how-to-use-mongodb-on-redhat-openshift-with-mongolab/)
- [Try MongoLab for Free on OpenShift](https://hub.openshift.com/quickstarts/11-mongolab)
- [Getting started with MongoDB, MongoLab, PHP and OpenShift](https://blog.openshift.com/getting-started-with-mongodb-mongolab-php-and-openshift/)